# Jar not reading audio files from inside the jar file

Tags: java, audio, jar, classloader

Okay, I've been at this for hours, I've checked other questions for help and I've tried all of the suggestions but none seem to work.

I am packaging a folder (called "audio") into my project with a bunch of .wav files in it. I am trying to reference those files, however they never get referenced inside the JAR, only outside in a separate folder called "audio".

```
try {
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    InputStream inn = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/audio/" + rangod + ".wav");
    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inn);
    clip.open(inputStream);
    FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    gainControl.setValue(-10.0f);
    clip.start();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem child seems to be

`InputStream inn = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/audio/" + rangod + ".wav");`

From what I've seen on other questions similar to this, having the "/" in front of "audio" is supposed to reference the audio folder INSIDE my jar file where as removing the "/" from in front of "audio" is supposed to reference the audio folder in the same directory as my jar file (ie: /desktop/audio)

Both methods seem to reference the same folder outside of my jar, and neither the one inside my jar.

My hierarchy is this:

```
audio
----[audio files]
net
----fragbashers
--------rgp
------------[class files]
```

Comment: Have you tried this.getClass().getResourceAsStream() instead of this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()?

Comment: Yep, it ends up giving the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, it was a really easy fix that I was overlooking. All my WAV files were saved in all lower case and I hadn't been converting the picked characters string to lowercase, so it didn't think the file existed.